# Hash functions in solidity

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I'am trying to hash two bytes16 variables to produce bytes32 or bytes16 variable :

```
bytes16 T=hash(bytes16 t1, bytes16 t2)
```

I looked in documentation but I didn't find anything

Answer (score 2):

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.10/units-and-global-variables.html#mathematical-and-cryptographic-functions lists the options. `keccak256` is most commonly used, but there's also `sha256` and `ripemd160`.

You'll want to combine those with `abi.encode` or `abi.encodePacked` to combine your inputs. E.g.:

```
bytes16 t1 = ...;
bytes16 t2 = ...;

bytes32 h = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(t1, t2));
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a hash functons that allows as to a create directly a bytes32 from 3 bytes16:        bytes32=func(t1,t2,t3)

Comment: All the hash functions accept a byte array, so you always need to convert to that first: `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(t1, t2, t3))`